# how to un-check Radio Button with single click which is checked by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a radio button which by default comes checked when the page loads ,and user can un_check if he want by single click but its not working in single click .. after three clicks the radio button un_checked.
Please see 
 [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/srt/0kyyfvy6/) . in the code the radio button with value 7 comes with checked by default , I can be able to un_check by clicking three times on it.is there any way to un_check it by just single click .Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

```
<td style="padding-right:0px;"><input type="radio" name="TEST" onclick=" var allRadios = document.getElementsByName('TEST'); var booRadio; var x = 0; for(x = 0; x < allRadios.length; x++){   allRadios[x].onclick = function() {     if (booRadio == this) {       this.checked = false;       booRadio = null;     }else{       booRadio = this;     }   }; }" value="7" CHECKED> 7</td>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using checkboxes with code that prevents more than one being selected? Standard radio button behaviour doesn't allow the user to set none to checked. Anyway, the problem is that you are binding the click handler that does the unchecking from *inside* another click handler, so the unchecking functionality isn't available until after the first click.

Comment: user can only select one value or none selected

Comment: Any chance you can put some line breaks in that code?  I can't read it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JQuery solution, if you assing a class `radioClass` to your radio buttons:

```
(function () {
    $('.radioClass').on('mouseup', function (e) {
    var xRadioB = this;
    if ($(xRadioB).is(':checked')) {
        setTimeout(function () {
        $(xRadioB).prop('checked', false);
      }, 5);
    }
  });
})();
```

JSfiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nfed1f7c/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I hope this is just for a test and that you will not embed events in your HTML as this will become very hard to manage, very quickly. I've manage to get a version working with some improve JavaScript. While I did not play with this for too long, I suspect there are better ways but that's a good first draft to get the results you desire: https://jsfiddle.net/0kyyfvy6/5/

```
var radioElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');

for (var iterator = 0; iterator < radioElements.length; iterator++) {
    var radioElement = radioElements[iterator];
  radioElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
        var radioElement = event.currentTarget;
      setTimeout(function () {
        radioElement.checked = '';
      }, 100);
    }
  })
}
```

I tried to have `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` and so on instead of the `setTimeout` but for some reasons it did not work. This seems relatively safe to implement depending on your use case.

Comment: yes this is just for test, I'm learning JS,Thanks for your help